# Erro ao usar scanner para setar atributos do objeto, nao sei como resolver

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Quando executo o codigo 
 aprecem junto no console, ja teitei usar else if, while, switch e nao estou conseguindo resolver .
o codigo esta assim:

public class PessoaEnderec
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);



    // Referencia Classe Endereco
    // Endereco 1
    Endereco end1 = new Endereco("Silva Guerra",109,"Patos de Minas","Minas Gerais");


    // Referencia Classe Pessoa
    // Pessoa 1
    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa(23,"Masculino",end1,"Higor Machado");
    {

    }

    System.out.println(p1.imprimir());

    //Pessoa 2
    Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa();
    {
        System.out.println("Digite Seu Nome: ");
        p2.setNome(entrada.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite Sua Idade: ");
        p2.setIdade(entrada.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Digite F pra sexo Feminino e M para Masculino");
        String entradaSexo = entrada.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        switch (entradaSexo)
        {
            case "f":
                p2.setSexo("Feminino");
                break;
            case "m":
                p2.setSexo("Masculino");
                break;
            default:
            {
                p2.setSexo("Nao Informado");
            }

        }

    }



    //Endereco 2
    Endereco end2 = new Endereco();
    {


        System.out.println("Digite o nome da sua rua");
        end2.setRua(entrada.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite o numero da sua casa");
        end2.setNumero(entrada.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Digite o nome da sua Cidade");
        end2.setCidade(entrada.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do seu estado");
        end2.setEstado(entrada.nextLine());
    }


    System.out.println(p2.imprimir());

    entrada.close();

}
```

}

Uso o IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3 como

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Troque isso:

```
String entradaSexo = entrada.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Por isso:

```
String entradaSexo = entrada.nextLine();
```

E também troque isso:

```
switch (entradaSexo)
```

Por isso:

```
switch (entradaSexo.toLowerCase())
```

Evitando assim de fazer a conversão para caixa baixa no input.